# How to check if a byte array in datatable is null or not

Tags: asp.net, arrays

```
if(oDataTable.Rows[0]["File"] != null) //byte array
{

}
```

File column in my table seems null. However when I try to check if it is null or not in the code part, it doesn't go to else part. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Could it possibly be `DBNull` instead of `null`? I would need to see more of your code to know for certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should check for DBNull with [Convert.IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull.aspx):

```
if(!Convert.IsDBNull(oDataTable.Rows[0]["File"]))
{
}
```

Comment: You can accept an answer in 6 minutes, it says ;) After that I'll.